# vb net backgroundworker + progress bar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i want to create automatic progress bar that will popped up when i ran my program..

my program has 6 function/sub which run query that took quite long time to completed, it's approximately around 1-2 minutes regarding `input`

i'm using `backgroundworker` to handle the threads and combine it with `progressbar`

here's my code

**RunWorkerAsync**

```
Private Sub ButtonX1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonX1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

**Do_work**

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    For i As Integer = 0 To 100000000
        create_tree()
        localtree()
        localfrek()
        create_combination()
        showresult()
        If i Mod 10000000 Then
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i / 100)
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

**ProgressChanged**

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

**RunWorkerCompleted**

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Task completed!")
End Sub
```

**the problem is**

1. the `the progress bar` didn't popped up
2. the function stop before completion

for the second problem i think it because the `for loop` that i use in `Do_work` event

i don't know the elapsed time of each function that i have, so i use random integer number in `for loop`

can you please help me to correct my program? thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be setting the `Visible` property of the `ProgressBar` before you call `RunWorkerAsync`.

Secondly, you should be comparing `i Mod 10000000` to something.

Thirdly, if `i` goes up to 10000000 then `i / 100` is going to go beyond 100.

Comment: on `formLoad` , i've already set the `progressBar` property to `True`.. Then set it into `false` on `backgroundworker` event `progressChanged`.. but it still not appearing..can you tell me how to comparing that.. i don't get the logic, how to set the duration of my program in `doWork` event because i don't know how to get total running time of my functions